# Google Chrome inserindo datepicker nos inputs

Tags: html5, google-chrome

Estou tendo problemas em tags `<input>` do tipo `type="date"`, como mostrado abaixo, quando o usuário utiliza Chrome (ou seja, no Firefox funciona como esperado).

```
<input name="dt_fim" id="dt_fim" type="date" placeholder="99/99/9999" value="<?=$dt_fim?>" maxlength="10" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/2[0-9]{3}" required>
```

O Chrome descarta o `value=""` quando recebe uma data pronta para o input, devolve no formato errado quando o usuário escreve manualmente e ainda por cima adiciona um *date picker* no input que eu não solicitei.

Ora, a solução óbvia é fazer o tipo ser texto `type="text"`, mas de acordo com o HTML5 eu poderia/deveria sinalizar como tipo data `type="date"`, porque assim o é.

Existe alguma coisa **que eu possa fazer nos meus fontes** à fim de corrigir ou previnir isso, além de definir o input como text? Isto é um erro meu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade está correto somente no chrome, o firefox não suporta o `input="date"` e usa o fallback de `input="text"`, se não deseja o datepicker, use o `input="text"` mesmo

http://caniuse.com/#search=type%3D%22date%22

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema tempos atrás, se você não tiver com muita pressa, pode usar o jquery para criar inputs com calendário.

Comment: De fato, foi o que eu fiz. Mudei os inputs de data para `type="text"` e, como eu já tinha tanto JQuery quanto uma biblioteca de máscaras no projeto, apenas precisei escrever em Javascripst este vínculo entre a máscara e os inputs. (Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow)